# Vim keymap and default keyboard layout

Tags: vim

I am using 2 keyboard layouts: russian and english. I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
set iminsert=0
```

The problem is that some of my files are opened with russian layout turned on and some are opened with english layout which I want to be default. (Search and normal mode commands are entered in english by default which is fine.)

May be this is connected with mkview/loadview autocommand but I can't find it out.

```
au BufWritePre *.* mkview
autocmd BufRead *.* silent loadview
```

Is there a way to force english layout by default?

Comment: It's nice to see a question with enough relevant info up front for a complete answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:help :mkview`:

```
The output of ":mkview" contains these items:
[...]
3. Restore mappings, abbreviations and options local to the window if
   'viewoptions' contains "options" or "localoptions".  For the options it
   restores only values that are local to the current buffer and values local
   to the window.
[...]
```

Both `keymap` and `iminsert` are buffer-local options and `options` is part of the default value of `viewoptions`.

Comment: Got it! It works with `set viewoptions=folds,cursor` but I found it more useful to append `autocmd BufRead *.* silent setlocal iminsert=0` after `autocmd ... loadview`. This forces `iminsert` option as I need and saves all other options. Thanks!